# scala parse json objects in order

Tags: scala, play-json

I have this following json input where I am trying to parse the name field in-order

```
scala> result
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"L0": 
{"name":"FASHION","id":"50000"},"L1":{"name":"ACCESSORIES AND TRAVEL","id":"51000"},"L2":{"name":"FASHION ACCESSORIES","id":"51001"},"L3":{"name":"MENS FASHION ACCESSORIES","id":"51100"},"L4":{"name":"MENS HATS","id":"51204"}}

scala> result \\ "name"
res5: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = List("ACCESSORIES AND TRAVEL", "MENS HATS", "MENS FASHION ACCESSORIES", "FASHION ACCESSORIES", "FASHION")
```

What I am trying is to get those names in-order like

```
List("FASHION", "ACCESSORIES AND TRAVEL", "FASHION ACCESSORIES", "MENS FASHION ACCESSORIES", "MENS HATS")
```

Is there a way to achieve that with play Json library?

Comment: What have you tried by yourself?

Comment: Yes. result \\ "name" is what I have right now. I am trying to do it using a regex but I am wondering if there's an easy way with play Json library itself

Comment: First have a look at the doc about how to parse/validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Play JSON I always use `case classes`. So your example would look like:

import play.api.libs.json._

```
val json = """{"L0": 
{"name":"FASHION","id":"50000"},"L1":{"name":"ACCESSORIES AND TRAVEL","id":"51000"},"L2":{"name":"FASHION ACCESSORIES","id":"51001"},"L3":{"name":"MENS FASHION ACCESSORIES","id":"51100"},"L4":{"name":"MENS HATS","id":"51204"}}
"""

case class Element(id: String, name: String)
object Element {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[Element] = Json.format[Element]
}

Json.parse(json).validate[Map[String, Element]] match {
  case JsSuccess(elems, _) => println(elems.toList.sortBy(_._1).map(e => e._2.name))
  case other => println(s"Handle exception $other")
}
```

What this gives you, is that you can sort the result by the key - the info that is lost in your solution.